# Using GridFS with Ming ODM in Turbogears

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, odm, turbogears2, ming

Ming supports GridFS start from 0.3 version, and i've used it in several Turbogears apps so far, but can't find any documentation of how to use GridFS with Ming,

This is what i've done so far, in my model `store.py` module :

```
#import statements

BookFile = fs.filesystem('books',DBSession.impl,)

class Book(MappedClass):
    """
    Book definition.
    """
    class __mongometa__:
        session = DBSession
        name = 'books'
        unique_indexes = [('title',),('author',),]

    _id = FieldProperty(s.ObjectId)
    title = FieldProperty(s.String)
    author = FieldProperty(s.String)
    isbn = FieldProperty(s.String)
    vendor = FieldProperty(s.String)
    _file = FieldProperty(s.ObjectId)

    def _get_file(self):
        return BookFile.m.find(dict(_id=self._file)).one()
    def _set_file(self, name, data):
        f = BookFile.m.put(name,data)
        self._file = f

    bookf = SynonymProperty(_get_file, _set_file)
```

As you can see, the `fs.filesystem` can't take an `ODMSession` (`ThreadLocalODMSession` in this case), so i have to drop down to basic `ming.Session` class by doing `DBSession.impl`.

What i'm worried is, Turbogears has been using ThreadLocalODMSession to adapt to multi-threaded environment, but what i'm doing above is giving the GridFS Connection the non thread-safe Session.

is that okay?
how should i do this correctly/safely?
Anyhelp would be appreciated,
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DBSession.impl` should be fine, as the `ming.Session` doesn't store any data.